# Switch Matrix block on handle rather than type

Tags: matrix

I've got a matrix with a Block type called textBlocks which Craft seems to be having trouble seeing.

The error is:

```
Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "textBlocks".
```

My template code is:

```
{% for block in entry.clientsContent %}

 {% switch block.type %}

{% case "text" %}


 <div class="small-{{ block.columns }}">
  <h3>{{ block.blockTitle }}</h3>
  <p>{{ block.blockContent }}</p>
 </div>


{% case "images" %}
 <ul class="small-block-grid-{{ block.blockGrid }}">
  {% for asset in block.images %}
   <li>
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" alt=""/>
   </li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>

 {% case "textBlocks" %}
 <ul class="small-block-grid-{{ textBlocks.blockGridNumber }}">
  {% for row in block.textBlocks %}
   <li><h5>{{ row.title }}</h5> <p>{{ row.content }}</p></li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endswitch %}

{% endfor %}
```

Am i getting this right here? When you do switch block.type is block.type the Block Type name?

See pic for my Matrix setup:
[image]

Comment: Ah no, i have just made a code error like a fool!

Answer (score 3):

I think you already spotted it.

Change:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-{{ textBlocks.blockGridNumber }}">
```

To:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-{{ block.blockGridNumber }}">
```

Comment: Yeah i'm an idiot.